# Custom sidebar filter in magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I want to customize a sidebar filter in the category magento 1.

I have it customizable but when reloading, it shows the body part when the header is not clicked.

I want to click on the header, the body will display

My code:

```
<div class="filter-cmvn">
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Geschlecht</h3>
        <span class="pull-right clickable"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="">
        <ol>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Damen<span class="count">(1265)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Herren<span class="count">(162)</span></a>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

Js

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
    jQuery(".panel-body").css("display","none");
    alert(1);
})
jQuery(document).on('click', '.panel-heading span.clickable', function(e){
    var thiss = jQuery(this);
    if(!thiss.hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
        thiss.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
        thiss.addClass('panel-collapsed');
        thiss.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    } else {
        thiss.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
        thiss.removeClass('panel-collapsed');
        thiss.find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
    }
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the body by default with css and let jquery do the job for you.

```
    <style> 
        .panel-body {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

    $('.panel-heading span.clickable').on('click', function(){
        $('.panel-body').slideToggle();
    });
```